# Spark SQL sql("<some aggregate query>").first().getDouble(0) give me inconsistent results

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, hivecontext

I have the below query which is supposed to find an average of the column values and return me the result which is a single number.

```
val avgVal = hiveContext.sql("select round(avg(amount), 4) from users.payment where dt between '2018-05-09' and '2018-05-09'").first().getDouble(0)
```

I'm facing inconsistent behavior at this statement. This often fails with below error however it gives non-NULL results when executed through Hive."

```
18/05/10 11:01:12 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 0 in null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 0 in null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAnyValAs(Row.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
```

The reason why I use HiveContext instead of SQLContext is that the later doesn't support some of the aggregation functions which I use extensively in my code.

Could you please help me understand why this problem occurs and how to solve?

Comment: What is the result of `hiveContext.sql("select round(avg(amount), 4) from users.payment where dt between '2018-05-09' and '2018-05-09'").first()`?

Comment: I get non-Null result when debugged. Infact my job completes successfully when I rerun for the same set data.

Comment: And I verified that I've all non-Null numbers in amount column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide query and get into two parts:

```
var result = hiveContext.sql("select round(avg(amount), 4) from users.payment where dt between '2018-05-09' and '2018-05-09'");
var first = result.first();
if (first != null && !first.isNullAt(0)) {
var avgVal = first.getDouble(0);
}
```

This would avoid NPE. This would also be needed in List and array.

For insert or update query, you even need to surround with `try...catch` block to catch runtime exception.

Comment: my point is why am I getting Null value when there is a proper genuine result for the query.

Comment: @puru did you try to debug the value of `result` in my code? Since HiveContext is subclass of SQLContext I don't see any difference between `sql(str)`. Actually, they are the same.

Comment: This is not correct. The `first ` itself may not be `null`, but `null` here is value at the index position.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the case and possible reasons when this exception can be thrown.

```
Row row = hiveContext.sql("select info, name, desc, id from users.payment where dt between '2018-05-09' and '2018-05-09'").first();
```

If the value of the `row` above returned something like:

```
[null, Kevin, cash, 300]
```

Trying to get `getDouble(0)` will lead to `java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 0 in null`

You can try the following approach:

```
Row row = hiveContext.sql("select round(avg(amount), 4) from users.payment where dt between '2018-05-09' and '2018-05-09'").first();

if (!row.isNullAt(0))
   double d = row.getDouble(0);
else
   logger.error("Value at index zero is null");
```

If you'll check the sources, the library class doing opposite:

```
private static Object getAnyValAs(Row $this, int i) {
    if($this.isNullAt(i)) {
        throw new NullPointerException((new StringContext(scala.Predef..MODULE$.wrapRefArray((Object[])(new String[]{"Value at index ", " is null"})))).s(scala.Predef..MODULE$.genericWrapArray(new Object[]{BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(i)})));
    } else {
        return $this.getAs(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Row of Dataset should be single double value. See `select rount(avg(amount), 4)`

Comment: I understand your concern about handling NullPointerException. I wanted to understand why the above code gives inconsistent results. Sometimes NULL and sometimes valid data when operated on the same set of an unchanged dataset.